# SVM parameters, how does it influence its performance

Tags: svm

I want to know how sensitive SVM performance is to its parameters. Is it as sensitive at backpropagation? is SVM a stable classifier? could you refer me to some papers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several notions in SVMs that are important to understand to get a grasp on how brittle it will be:

**Margin-based** 
Only a few points are used to separate your classes: the support vectors. This means you use the "border cases" to separate your data. The reason to do this is simple. It corresponds to setting the weights of all the points that are no support vectors to zero. This is a consideration of **sparsity**. A lot of zeros means you have to do less multiplications. If the data is linear separable there is only line that can be drawn with maximum margin, so there will be no parameters whatsoever involved. And hence no sensitivity with respect to parameters either. In the nontrivial case of separability in some high dimensional space, this is not the case. A kernel, e.g. the Gaussian kernel, comes with the usual σ parameter for variance. The more complex the kernel, the more awkward the separation can be (see [this blog post](http://mlstat.wordpress.com/tag/incremental-complexity-svm/)).

**Inseparable classes**
For inseparable classes things have to be invented to get a proper problem again. For geometric intuition the paper [Duality and Geometry in SVM classifiers](http://pdf.aminer.org/000/334/459/duality_and_geometry_in_svm_classifiers.pdf) is interesting. It visualizes the problem as a reduced convex hull around the data points such that there is again a separable plane between the two classes. This is the dual of expanding the margin (through softening) to allow the incorporation of "improper" points. How "misfits" are handled leads to (tunable) parameters. It is easy to visualize for example a data point very far into the region of the other class. If data is like that it would probably lead you to consider **robustness** with respect to how you incorporate slack variables or functions. This is encapsulated often in the "misclassification penalty" C.

If you really want to know what kind of assumptions underlie support vector machines, it often is beneficial to search for **Bayesian interpretations**. Be careful though, they might just change the hinge loss to least squares and actually describe something totally different from ordinary SVMs. The paper I recommend is [Bayesian Methods for Support Vector Machines: Evidence and Predictive Class Probabilities](http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/~psollich/papers_pdf/SVM_MLMM_Kluwer.pdf) from Sollich.